# How to get Azure Storage account key programmatically using Java?

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk

How can we get Azure Storage account access key using Java? What all details are required to get that.

Thanks, 
Prit

Answer (score 0):

To get storage account access keys by using java, you can use Azure Rest API. A java sdk is available, it lets you manage easily your storage accounts.

To get access keys you need to use the resource Group name where you storage account is and the storage account name. Once you get back your storage account using those informations, a method called "keys" returns access keys.

```
List<StorageAccountKey> storageAccountKeys = storageAccount.keys();
```

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-java-manage-storage-accounts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/storage/samples/ManageStorageAccount.java) is a complete documentation sample.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Thibaut. This sample doesn't seems to be using standard java SDK provided by Azure.

Answer (score 0):

@Prit, You need to use Azure Storage Service Management SDK for Java to get account keys, please see the steps below.

1. Create a self-signed certificate and upload it in the tab `MANAGEMENT CERTIFICATES` of `SETTINGS` on Azure classic portal, please refer to the [blog](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/08/25/consuming-windows-azure-service-management-api-in-java/).

I. Create a certificate using Java keytool, see the commands below.

> - keytool -genkeypair -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore WindowsAzureKeyStore.jks -keysize 2048 -storepass "test123";
> - keytool -v -export -file D:\WindowsAzureSMAPI.cer -keystore WindowsAzureKeyStore.jks 
>     -alias mydomain

II. Upload the `.cer` file as below.
[image]

You need to add these dependencies into your `pom.xml` file of maven project.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-svc-mgmt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-svc-mgmt</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-svc-mgmt-storage -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-svc-mgmt-storage</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my code for getting account keys.

```
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.utils.KeyStoreType;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.configuration.ManagementConfiguration;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.storage.StorageManagementClient;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.storage.StorageManagementService;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.storage.models.StorageAccountGetKeysResponse;

public class AccountKeys {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, ServiceException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

        String uri = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
        String subscriptionId = "<subscription-id>";
        String keyStorePath = "<path>/WindowsAzureKeyStore.jks";
        String keyStorePassword = "test123";
        String storageName

        Configuration config =     ManagementConfiguration.configure(
                    new URI(uri),
                    subscriptionId,
                    keyStorePath, // the file path to the JKS
                    keyStorePassword, // the password for the JKS
                    KeyStoreType.jks // flags that I'm using a JKS keystore
                  );
        StorageManagementClient client = StorageManagementService.create(config);
        StorageAccountGetKeysResponse response = client.getStorageAccountsOperations().getKeys(storageName);
        String pk = response.getPrimaryKey();
        String sk = response.getSecondaryKey();
        System.out.println(pk);
        System.out.println(sk);
    }
}
```

As reference, the related REST API is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460785.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Peter. Azure recommends to use ARM now and not certificates, so there should be some way without using certificate.